# The Visual Studio editor and long lines

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

Visual Studio (and most other editors like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad)) doesn't handle long lines well. For instance, I use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Objects) (SMO) to generate database scripts. Some of these auto generated SQL scripts have single lines with thousand and thousand of characters in one single line. When I open that in Visual Studio it just freezes.. or it slows down to the point that it becomes unusable.

Is there any text editor you know of that handles long lines efficiently? (and ideally supports syntax highlighting?

Comment: *Not* Scintilla/SciTE. Excellent though they are, they don't deal with very long lines at all well.

Comment: What sort of line length we talking about here? Are these lines one or two thousand characters in length or many tens/hundreds of thousand characters in length? I would have though most text editors could handle the first case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my experience, [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) handles long lines quite well.

Comment: Really? I find SciTE doesn't handle them at all well.  The caret insists on leaping to the very edge of the screen, for instance.